# Background Image Fluid Resizing

Tags: background, fluid-layout

I am using an background image which is inside a header tag. The coding looks like this:

```
<div id "header">
<div id "logo">
<div id "nav">


</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The header is inside a container element which is sized at width:75%. The logo image is 1024px wide and 75px height. I am trying to find a solution that would keep the logo image which is inside a background tag at 100% width of the container element and when re-sized it  is re-sized proportionally.

The solution I have thought of is

```
background-size:auto;
```

I have chosen the 1024px as it would accommodate most screen. The min-width would be 780px and the max-width:1024px.

What is the best solution to have this background image re-size in proportion the the visitor screen and the container element which it is in.

Thanks

Comment: A background image won't force the ratio of its element without JS. Use a `<img>` instead.

Comment: fluid seems like a bad tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 background-size: 100%;
```

Comment: This isnt working. The top 15px of the image are showing but the rest is cropped off. I am trying to find the best cross browser solution.

Comment: does the container div have `height: 100%`?

Answer (score 0):

The best method I found to work was

min-width:100%;

Answer (score 0):

The only way to resize background is with JavaScript.

The code using jQuery is here: https://gist.github.com/epoberezkin/5070642